# How to add a string into javafx ListView?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am trying to add a result that I get as a string into the ListView container, as I think that my result should be in an ArrayList to be added but I couldn't get them converted ! This is the error appears underneath **add** within `messageArrived` method `The method add(ArrayList<Wallet>) in the type List<ArrayList<Wallet>> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
public class MainController implements MqttCallback   {
@FXML
private ListView<ArrayList<Wallet>> RoomA;

 @Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    String attemptMessageJson = message.toString();
    Wallet rfidObject = gson.fromJson(attemptMessageJson, Wallet.class);        
    RoomA.getItems().add(rfidObject.getWalletName()); // error explained above
     }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. As has been suggested in your last question already - do it __now__!

Comment: also: if you don't understand the error message, it's time for learning some basic java: here that would be generics (hint: you can only add the specified type to the List)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what the type parameter for ListView does.  Did you want each selectable item in the ListView to be a *collection of wallets?*  Or did you want each item in the ListView to be a single Wallet?

Answer (score -1):

Add the `Wallet` to the list and make its `toString` return what you want displayed.

Also `ListView<ArrayList<Wallet>>` should just be `ListView<Wallet>`

Comment: no, never-ever override toString for application reasons - instead use a custom cell that shows the property